# Unable to call UITableViewDelegate tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) from UITableView subclass

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift

I have a subclass of UITableView that does some custom touch handling. I'm porting it from Objective-C to Swift.

For some reason, I'm unable to call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method without getting the following error, even though it happily autocompletes it for me:

`Could not find an overload for 'tableView' that accepts the supplied arguments`

This example code throws the above error:

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(index: 1)    
self.delegate?.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)?
```

Is this a compiler/framework bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you actually implement the method somewhere?

Comment: It's a method defined in the UITableViewDelegate protocol, so it's already defined. And yes my delegate implements it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is optional, so you have to account for that. You can use optional chaining:

```
self.delegate?.tableView?(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

or if you want to force it to be called (at risk of crashing your program if it has not been implemented:

```
self.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn I tried that, but I guess I didn't. So the issue was that I put the ? at the end of the call rather than after "tableView" and the compiler error was not clear that this was the issue.